# Scala: Wrapper around List, still use zipping?

Tags: scala

For convenience, I have built a wrapper around a `scala.collection.immutable.List`. However, I realised that the `zipped` function does not work with the wrapper, of course.

What trait does the new class have to extend, to make this still possible? Or am I (coming from Java) using a completely wrong approach for Scala?

Comment: Unless you explain why you wrapped `List`, nobody can tell whether you are "using a completely wrong approach for Scala."

Comment: If you are doing it to add methods then you are better off by using pimp my library.

Comment: to add methods, yes!

Comment: Please add some sample code. What you want to do is probably not that difficult, but it will be tough to help without knowing what that is. @ reply me if you edit the question.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on the comments, if you just want to add new methods, use an implicit class instead of a wrapper:

```
implicit class ListOps[A](private val xs: List[A]) extends AnyVal {
  def stripe(take: Int, drop: Int): List[A] =
    xs.sliding(take, take + drop).flatten.toList
}

// test
val z = List(1 to 20: _*)
z.stripe(2, 3) // List(1, 2, 6, 7, 11, 12, 16, 17)
```